# String Slicing Into a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to enter a string into the one_frame function ():

```
one_frame("catatgdaftgaatg")
```

What I am trying to do is return a list `["atgdaf","atg"]`. whenever I find `"atg"` in the string, I want to grab that `"atg"` and whatever is after that until I reach either `"taa" "tga" "tag"`. This is what I have so far but it only returns `["atg"]`.

```
def get_orf(dna_seq):

for x in dna_seq:
    if("taa" in dna_seq or "tag" in dna_seq or "tga" in dna_seq):
        dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("taa","")
        dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("tga","")
        dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("tag","")
        return dna_seq
    else:
        return dna_seq

def one_frame(dna):
    c=0
    q=3
    dna_list=[]
    dna_string=""
    while(q<=len(dna)):
        dna_string=dna[c:q]
        c=c+3
        q=q+3
        if(dna_string=="atg"):
            dna_list.append(get_orf(dna_string))
```

Comment: problem is dna_string is always 3 characters long..you will never get "atgdaf" if the character length is always 3....

Answer (score 1):

```
dna_list.append(get_orf(dna_string+dna[c:q+3]))
```

<strike>just update the append function...
since the length of dna_string is always 3..you will never get the desired result which is of 6 character</strike>

**update:-**
I forget the other conditions you mentioned.

```
def get_orf(dna_seq):
  for x in dna_seq:
    # print dna_seq
    if("taa" in dna_seq or "tag" in dna_seq or "tga" in dna_seq):
        dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("taa","")
        dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("tga","")
        dna_seq=dna_seq.replace("tag","")
        if('atg' in dna_seq[3:]):
          dna_seq="atg"+dna_seq[3:].replace("atg","")
        return dna_seq
    else:
        return dna_seq

def one_frame(dna):
    c=0
    q=3
    dna_list=[]
    dna_string=""
    while(q<=len(dna)):
        dna_string=dna[c:q]
        c=c+3
        q=q+3
        print dna_string
        if(dna_string=="atg"):
            dna_list.append(get_orf(dna[c-3:]))

    print dna_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your task, then you could use the `split` method mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with *atg* delimiter. You'll get the list of substrings, then for each substring you could get index of occurences of *taa*, *tga*, *tag* substrings, and cut substring at minimal index.

Answer (score 0):

In your method, you're moving by a step of 3. That is why you're not able to catch the second `atg`. And about your second problem, you're always passing only 3 characters to the `get_orf` method. You need to pass the whole string to find the characters you need.

```
def get_orf(dna_seq):
    for counter, val in enumerate(dna_seq):
        if val == "t" and counter < len(dna_seq)-2:
            if dna_seq[counter+1:counter+3] in ["aa", "ag"]:
                return dna_seq[:counter]
            if dna_seq[counter+1:counter+3] == "ga":
                return dna_seq[:counter]
    return dna_seq

def one_frame(dna):
    c = 0
    dna_list = []
    while c <= len(dna)-3:
        dna_string = dna[c:]
        if dna_string.startswith("atg"):
            dna_list.append(get_orf(dna_string))
        c += 1
    return dna_list
```